# Multiple selections with a python loop

Tags: arcpy, loop, arcgis-10.6

I am very new to Python and have no idea about how to write a python loop to do selections for ArcGIS. I already finished writing selection codes with different conditions. Is there anyone helping me revise my codes with a python loop?

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = "D:/STAR/STARproject.gdb"
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management('wqi_Conshp_clip27171','wqi_Conshp_clip27171')

#Select level 1 gridcode<=14.3
selection1 = '"gridcode"<=14.3'
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management('wqi_Conshp_clip27171','NEW_SELECTION',selection1)

arcpy.Statistics_analysis('wqi_Conshp_clip27171','stats27171wqi_Conlevel1',[["Shape_Area","sum"]])
#summarize the selected features
arcpy.AddField_management('stats27171wqi_Conlevel1','rate','DOUBLE')
arcpy.CalculateField_management('stats27171wqi_Conlevel1','rate','!SUM_Shape_Area!/{}'.format(Sum_Area27171),'PYTHON_9.3') 
#Sum_Area27171 is a variable and already defined in the workspace

#select level 2 14.3<gridcode<=25.6

selection2 =  '"gridcode">14.3 AND "gridcode"<=28.6'
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management('wqi_Conshp_clip27171','NEW_SELECTION',selection2)

arcpy.Statistics_analysis('wqi_Conshp_clip27171','stats27171wqi_Conlevel2',[["Shape_Area","sum"]])

arcpy.AddField_management('stats27171wqi_Conlevel2','rate','DOUBLE')
arcpy.CalculateField_management('stats27171wqi_Conlevel2','rate','!SUM_Shape_Area!/{}'.format(Sum_Area27171),'PYTHON_9.3') 

#select level 3 28.6<gridcode<=42.9

selection3 =  '"gridcode">28.6 AND "gridcode"<=42.9'
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management('wqi_Conshp_clip27171','NEW_SELECTION',selection3)
arcpy.Statistics_analysis('wqi_Conshp_clip27171','stats27171wqi_Conlevel3',[["Shape_Area","sum"]])

arcpy.AddField_management('stats27171wqi_Conlevel3','rate','DOUBLE')
arcpy.CalculateField_management('stats27171wqi_Conlevel3','rate','!SUM_Shape_Area!/{}'.format(Sum_Area27171),'PYTHON_9.3') 

#select level 4 42.9<gridcode<=57.2

selection4 =  '"gridcode">42.9 AND "gridcode"<=57.2'
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management('wqi_Conshp_clip27171','NEW_SELECTION',selection4)


arcpy.Statistics_analysis('wqi_Conshp_clip27171','stats27171wqi_Conlevel4',[["Shape_Area","sum"]])

arcpy.AddField_management('stats27171wqi_Conlevel4','rate','DOUBLE')
arcpy.CalculateField_management('stats27171wqi_Conlevel4','rate','!SUM_Shape_Area!/{}'.format(Sum_Area27171),'PYTHON_9.3')

#merge these results
arcpy.Merge_management(['stats27171wqi_Conlevel1','stats27171wqi_Conlevel2','stats27171wqi_Conlevel3',
                    'stats27171wqi_Conlevel4'],'stats27171wqi_ConMerge')
```

As you can see, there are four conditions above. Actually, I have another three similar conditions. I am wondering how to combine these selections together with a loop in python to make the work as simple as possible.

Comment: It looks like for each condition you are performing a selection, adding fields, and calculating fields. Because of this I'd create a function in which you pass the query and fieldname, and then loop through calls to this function.

Comment: @smiller, thanks for your help. Writing a function is a kind of complex for me. Do you know where I can find similar examples for looping or functions? Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above question is part of a script. The purpose of the script is to create a buffer and do selections based on the percentage of different values. Here is the updated version of my script and hope it is useful for other users.

```
import pandas as pd
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = "D:/WQ.gdb"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True #overwrite the exsiting files

selection1 =  '"gridcode"<=14.3'
selection2 =  '"gridcode">14.3 AND "gridcode"<=28.6'
selection3 =  '"gridcode">28.6 AND "gridcode"<=42.9'
selection4 =  '"gridcode">42.9 AND "gridcode"<=57.2'
selection5 =  '"gridcode">57.2 AND "gridcode"<=71.5'
selection6 =  '"gridcode">71.5 AND "gridcode"<=85.8'
selection7 =  '"gridcode">85.8 AND "gridcode"<=100'
#these are the selection conditions for 7 levels of WQI

selections = [selection1, selection2, selection3, selection4,
          selection5, selection6, selection7]

for point in random: #random is a list including all unique values of a field
    pointname = "n" + str(point)
    fieldname = 'ARC_'
    whereClause = """{0} = {1}""".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(pointlayer, fieldname),point)  
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(pointlayer,pointlayer)  

    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(pointlayer,'NEW_SELECTION',whereClause)

    print pointname

    buffername = pointname + "buffer25"
    #define the buffer's name
    arcpy.Buffer_analysis(pointname,buffername,"25 miles")
    #make a 5 miles buffer around the selected point
    print buffername

    bufferclip = scenairo + "25" + "clip" +pointname
    #define a clip name
    arcpy.Clip_analysis(scenairo,buffername,bufferclip)
    print bufferclip

    #######################################################################
    #calculate the area of the buffer
    list = []
    rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(bufferclip)
    SumArea = bufferclip + "Area"

    for row in rows:
        area = row.getValue("Shape_Area")
        list.append(area)
        SumArea = sum(list)
    print SumArea

    #######################################################################

    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(bufferclip,bufferclip)

    count = 0 #define a number for the name of selected name
    statisticstables = []
    selectionmerge = bufferclip + "_Merge" 

    for selection in selections:

        count = count + 1
        selectionname = bufferclip + "level" + str(count)
        #define the selection name such as level1 and level2
        statisticstables.append(selectionname)

        ratename = "rate" + str(point)
        arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(bufferclip,'NEW_SELECTION',selection)
        arcpy.Statistics_analysis(bufferclip,selectionname,[["Shape_Area","sum"]])

        ######checking if the selectionname is empty and then add a new row with zeros if empty
        fields = ['FREQUENCY','Sum_Shape_Area'] #do not set OBJECTID

        if int(arcpy.GetCount_management(selectionname).getOutput(0)) == 0:

            icur = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(selectionname,fields)
            icur.insertRow([0,0])
            del icur

        arcpy.AddField_management(selectionname,ratename,'DOUBLE') #add a new field
        arcpy.CalculateField_management(selectionname,ratename,'!SUM_Shape_Area!/{}'.format(SumArea),'PYTHON_9.3') 
        print selectionname

        arcpy.Merge_management(statisticstables, selectionmerge) #merge all level tables into one table

    pathname = "scenairo" + str(i)
    outpath = "D:\\STAR\\" + pathname
    outresult = outpath + "\\" + selectionmerge + ".xls"
    arcpy.TableToExcel_conversion(selectionmerge,outresult)
    print outresult
```